# datatable row start and end grouping

Tags: javascript, datatable

I tried the function below, how can i add css style for the grouping header and footer? For the footer, maybe it is possible, but how can i do it for the header?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        order: [[2, 'asc']],
        rowGroup: {             
            endRender: function ( rows, group ) {
                var salaryAvg = rows
                    .data()
                    .pluck(5)
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return a + b.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')*1;
                    }, 0) / rows.count();
                salaryAvg = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '$').display( salaryAvg );

                var ageAvg = rows
                    .data()
                    .pluck(3)
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return a + b*1;
                    }, 0) / rows.count();

                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append( '<td colspan="3">Averages for '+group+'</td>' )
                    .append( '<td>'+ageAvg.toFixed(0)+'</td>' )
                    .append( '<td/>' )
                    .append( '<td>'+salaryAvg+'</td>' );
            },
            dataSrc: 2
        }
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just css

```
tr.group{
    background-color: #690505 !important;
    color: white !important;
}

tr.group:hover {
    background-color: #871818 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Can i ask, is it allow to get the value of the column if it is an input field(text box) by using pluck()?

Comment: see this [example](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43578/issue-in-search-when-used-with-row-grouping) use the function intval @Zidance

Answer (score 0):

```
table.dataTable tr.group td{
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#e0e0e0
}
```